# Disable dynamically imported JS files cache

Tags: javascript, dynamic-import

I need some mechanism to reload dynamically imported JS files in browser (using `import()`). When I use simple `<script src='index.js'>` loading this task may be resolved this way: `<script src='index.js?v=1.4.2'>`. How can I use something similar with dynamic importing? Is there some way of adding hash to generated by Webpack files' names?